# Gxt combo box selection arrow is not properly aligned in GXT4.0

Tags: css, gwt, gxt

I have upgraded the GXT from 3.0 to 4.0 and combox box arrow is showing like in the image[image]

It works fine in GXT3.0.It is dispalyed fine in GWT Debug mode also in GXT4.0.

I had created Combo Box exactly with the following link.
http://examples.sencha.com/gxt/4.0.0/#ExamplePlace:comboboxstyled

```
**I am using gray theme.**
```

**gxt-all.css file**

The following Css I have applied to combo box but I am not sure it is applying or not.

```
.x-combo-list {
    border-color:#98c0f4;
    background-color:#ddecfe;
    font:normal 12px tahoma, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.x-combo-list-inner {
    background-color:#fff;
}

.x-combo-list-hd {
    font:bold 11px tahoma, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#15428b;
    background-image: url(../images/default/layout/panel-title-light-bg.gif);
    border-bottom-color:#98c0f4;
}

.x-resizable-pinned .x-combo-list-inner {
    border-bottom-color:#98c0f4;
}

.x-combo-list-item {
    border-color:#fff;
}

.x-combo-list .x-combo-selected{
    border-color:#a3bae9 !important;
    background-color:#dfe8f6;
}

.x-combo-list .x-toolbar {
    border-top-color:#98c0f4;
}

.x-combo-list-small {
    font:normal 11px tahoma, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

**CustomComboBoxView.css file**

@eval borderColor com.sencha.gxt.core.client.resources.ThemeStyles.get().borderColor();

.view {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid borderColor;
  -moz-outline: none;
  outline: 0 none;
  position: relative;
}

@if (is("ie6"))  {
  .view {
    overflow: auto; 
  }
} @else {
  .view {
    overflow-y: auto; 
  }
}

.item {
   border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    font-family: tahoma, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-size-adjust: none;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    white-space: normal;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.over {
  gwt-image: 'selectedBackground';
  height: auto;
  border: 1px dotted #DDDDDD !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sel {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 50% #DFE8F6;
  border: 1px dotted #A3BAE9 !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////

EntryPointSample Class file

      public interface CustomListViewResources extends
        ListViewDefaultResources {

             @Override
            @Source({"com/test/sample/clients/gwt/client/panel/CustomComboBoxView.css"})
          CustomListViewStyle css();

         }

         interface CustomListViewStyle extends
         ListViewDefaultAppearance.ListViewDefaultStyle { }


        private final SampleProperties sampleProperties = GWT.create(SampleProperties.class);
        private ComboBox<Sample> SampleComboBox;


        final ListViewDefaultResources resources = GWT.create(CustomListViewResources.class);


        final ListViewDefaultAppearance<Sample> appearance = new ListViewDefaultAppearance<Sample>(resources);

        final ListView<Sample, String> listView =
                        new ListView<Sample, String>(sampleLocationListStore, sampleProperties.name(),
                        appearance);

        sampleComboBox =
                        new ComboBox<Sample>(sampleLocationListStore, sampleProperties.nameLabel(), listView);
        sampleComboBox.setWidth(150);
        sampleComboBox.setTypeAhead(true);

        sampleComboBox.setTriggerAction(ComboBoxCell.TriggerAction.ALL);

        sampleComboBox.addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<Sample>() {
            @Override
            public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<Sample> companySelectionEvent) {


              }
            });

        testDropdownLabel = new FieldLabel(sampleComboBox, constants.labelTest());
        testDropdownLabel.setLabelWidth(50);
        widget.add(testDropdownLabel);
```

Comment: Is there any CSS applied to the combobox? Have you cleared your cache to make sure no old CSS is applied?

Comment: Yes CSS has been applied on the check box but I am not getting why css is not working properly in GXT4.0 but working perfectly fine in GXT3.1.4.

I have followed the exact steps defined in http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/gss_migration.html by converting into GSS but why It is failing in GXT4.0

Comment: Can you clarify your question by posting some code?

Comment: which GWT version are you using? Can you provide a small example, that shows the bug?

Comment: I am using GXT4.0. Everything is working fine in GXt 3.1.4 but UI becomes so messy in GXt4.0. I just wanted to know what is changed in GXT 4.0 by which UI becomes so massy..I have done everything by converting css to gss. but was not successful.

Comment: @EI Hoss, I have attached an image of gender combo box where the arrow is not coming properly.Please refer to question to see the bug.

Comment: Which version of GWT are you using?

Comment: I have worked with GXT 3.1 and GXT 4.0 and did not run into this problems. So it looks like there is something special in your code. To solve your issue, you have to provide more informations.

Comment: I am using GWT 2.7.0 version. Which kind of information i have to provide.

Comment: You should provide an EntryPoint that contains the code of the combobox and the host page.

Comment: @EI Hoss, I have added a sample code, Please let me know if you need extra information.